# Liferay portal error

Tags: java, liferay

I need open new browser window with PDF format.I have jsp,javaservelt with PDF stuff.This same code working in webserver.But it is not working in Lifray portal.When i click the button , it shows resource not found.

I have tried with java servlet class and struts, both not open the PDF.

Portal error Message:

[PortalImpl:2948] Current URL /web/guest/PDFOpenExer generates exception: null

What i have to do open the new PDF ?

Please help me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem at all. You might want to add more details - e.g. do you need to stream the PDF to the client yourself or could you use Liferay's Document Library? From where are you linking to the PDF? WebContent (Liferay's CMS)? You might want to provide simplified sample code.

Answer (score 0):

URL /web/guest/PDFOpenExer maybe is not a page maanged by liferay. It doesnt exists.